# CMake add linker options after .obj files

Tags: cmake, linker, embedded, linker-errors, static-linking

Cross compiling an executable for an embedded system with CMake requires me to manually add link options to link libc, libgcc and whatnot. However using target_link_options for that results in a linker call where all those additional link options are added in front of all the object files generated from my actual code. I believe that this is the wrong linking order and it causes "duplicate symbol errors" whenever I try to overwrite weak symbols from the standard library (e.g. __cxa_pure_virtual).

Here is an exemplar of the output I get from the linking stage

```
"/usr/bin/ld.lld" 
--gc-sections 
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/crti.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/crtbegin.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/crtn.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/crtend.o 
--start-group -lstdc++_nano -lm -lgcc -lc_nano --end-group 
my.obj  ///< Shoudln't object files and application libs be linked first?
libmylib.a
-Bstatic 
-L/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/lib/baremetal 
-L/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/ 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/ 
-T ldscript.ld
-o myelf
```

Is there any way to solve this in CMake?

Comment: replace `target_link_options` with `target_link_libraries`. `the wrong linking order` As the name suggests, `target_link_options` adds _options_ to the linker. And typically options are specified before anything else. `and it causes "duplicate symbol errors"` My guess is this is caused by the `--start-group`/`--end-group` options.

Comment: Well, that was a quick fix. If you post that as answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Linker options are _typically_ added before objects, but not always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target_link_options` specifies options to the linker - and typically options are specified before anything else. Use `target_link_libraries` to link with libraries.